Can we change the category of our site?
I extremely believe Quantitative finance is a science. The history of this branch of mathematics can tell us that Quantitative finance is a science, not business. Can we change this situation? How? 

maybe it's an art, like much of mathematics ;) ?

You are so funny ;)
